# Error al iniciar sesion despues de un login y logout Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Que tal compañeros, tengo un problema pero no he identificado el problema. He configurado un filtro para la concurrencia de sesiones, pero, si realizo las siguientes acciones en orden como se muestra, me es imposible reingresar a la aplicación. Los pasos son los siguientes:

1. En una pestaña se abre: login->ingreso usuario y contraseña->home
2. En otra pestaña realizo lo mismo que en el paso 1, pero lanza excepción  por el filtro de concurrencia lo cual es correcto
3. En la pestaña del primer punto hago logout y todo parece normal.
4. Vuelvo a la aplicación: login->ingreso usuario y contraseña->no puedo entrar a la aplicación

Este es mi `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>ms-iex</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/securityContext.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcherContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/login/LoginView.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Este es mi `SecurityContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <!-- 
        Contiene las clases para el mapeo de los usuarios de LDAP
        ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________     
     -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pyxis.iex.security"/>

    <!-- 
        Permite el uso de EL en JSP con etiquetas de Spring Security
        ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________     
     -->
    <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />   

    <!-- 
        Configuracion de Login, Interceptores y Filtros
        ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________     
    -->

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">

        <!-- Filtros personalizados para el control de concurrencia -->
        <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/error" />

        <!-- Login Form personalizada -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
                             username-parameter="custom_username"
                             password-parameter="custom_password"
                             authentication-success-handler-ref="Redirect"
                             authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />

        <!-- Logout personalizado -->                            
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" 
                         invalidate-session="true" 
                         logout-success-url="/login?logout=true"
                         delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,User,UserID" />                                 

        <!-- Interceptores de aplicacion -->    
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>        
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/gerente**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR_OPERATIVO')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/enlace**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ENLACE_MESA_SERVICIO') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR_OPERATIVO')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/administrador**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR')"/>

        <!-- Manejo de sesiones -->     
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"
                                     invalid-session-url="/login"
                                     session-authentication-error-url="/error"
                                     />
        <!-- Proteccion para XSS -->                
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

    </security:http>

    <!-- 
        Configuracion de LDAP
        ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________     
     -->
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People"
                                               group-search-base="ou=Roles"
                                               group-search-filter="uniqueMember={0}"
                                               server-ref="ldapServer"
                                               user-context-mapper-ref="contextMapper"
                                               /> 
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:ldap-server id="ldapServer" 
                          url="ldap://192.168.40.105:10389/dc=iex,dc=com" 
                          manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system"
                          manager-password="secret"  />     

    <bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
      <constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
      <constructor-arg value="ou=Roles"/>
      <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
      <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
      <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        Configuración de concurrencia de sesiones
        ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
     -->     
    <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" /> 

    <bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" >
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/error"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

He intentado eliminar las cookies, pero sigue sin dejarme entrar a la aplicación, cualquier experiencia suya será bienvenida, gracias.

Comment: Solo como nota, al usar este tipo de manejo de sesiones en el que solamente puedes tener la sesión original, vienen algunos problemas como el siguiente: puede que un usuario ingrese correctamente a la aplicación pero de forma accidental se cierra el navegador, al abrirlo de nuevo e intentar iniciar sesión no podrá hacerlo ya que no hay manera de saber que la sesión anterior fue terminada ya que nunca cerró sesión.

Answer (score 0):

en el archivo web.xml debes agregar un escucha para que se de cuenta cuando cierras sesión:

> < listener> < listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEvent
>   Publisher

Comment: < listener> < listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEvent
Publisher </listener-class ></ listener>

Comment: Tu pueder editar tu respuesta si consideras que falta agregar algo mas de codigo. Solo haz click en [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/48237/edit)